# Can't export particles as 1 object

Tags: mesh, export, .fbx

I have followed this tutorial and finished creating a 3D donut object:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rKPSB8tcXhQ

I'm trying to export the donut as an FBX to import it into a Davinci Resolve fusion clip but every sprinkle shows up as an invidivual 3D object node and the donut is transparent (in Davinci Resolve). The sprinkles were created by making 4 slightly differently shaped sprinkle objects in a collection and then attaching them to the icing by weight painting the icing object and using the particle emission hair effect.

I tried to follow this post: [Convert Particle System to Mesh (Collection NOT Object)?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/161294/convert-particle-system-to-mesh-collection-not-object)
and use a modifier to make all of the particles seperate objects and then join them with `Ctrl J`. That made the sprinkles look like a single object in Blender but they still gets split into a million sprinkle object nodes in Davinci Resolve.

So in total I have 2 questions:

1. How do you get the sprinkles to be exported as 1 mesh instead of a million 3D objects (as it appears in Davinci Resolve)?
2. how do I get the donut to not export transparent?

P.S. I'm much more concerned with the first question. The second one is not as big of a deal.

Comment: What happens if you join all the sprinkles with Ctrl+J, as you did, but then join it with the rest of the donut as well, so it's all one single object? Does that still import as multiple objects?